# Invoke block passed to pipeline step with parameters, from plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to write a Jenkins plugin that provides Step `myStep` which expects a block with a single parameter per below

```
myStep { someParameter -> <user code> }
```

I've found that `BodyInvoker` ( retrieved from `StepContext.newBodyInvoker()` ) provides no facilities to invoke the user provided block with parameters.

Expanding the environment would not be ideal, even though the type of the parameter is serializable ( to/from String ), i'd have to provide additional helpers to carry out this serialization, e.g

```
myStep { deserialize "${env.value}" <user code> }
```

do i have any other option to pass a non-string type in to the provided block? would type information of the parameter survive even if i did?

nb: i understand you can return a value from your `Execution.run()` which will be the return value of the step in the pipeline. It's just that in a related shared pipeline library i'm already heavily leaning in to this pattern of:

```
withFoo { computedFoo ->
  # something with computedFoo
  withBar computedFoo { computedBar ->
  }
}
```

i prefer this over

```
computedFoo = withFoo
# something with computedFoo
withBar(computedFoo)
```

..then again, i couldn't find any plugins pulling this off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no matter how close i look at `workflow-step-api-plugin` this doesn't seem possible today. The options are:

- expand the environment context with a string value
- add a custom object to the context ( requires access to step context in        pipeline )
- use a return value